# PhoneGap под Android, iPhone

Tags: android, html, iphone, css, javascript

Посоветуйте статьи по этому вопросу пожалуйста, желательно на русском, можно и на английском. Киньте туториалов, на офф сайты фонГэп не шлите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Introduction to PhoneGap](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3964572)
- [PhoneGap Beginner's Guide](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3919801)